# A counterexample. The pointwise limit of measurable function may not be measurable if the range is not metrizable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is the exercise 8.14 of Donald L. Cohn's measure theory. There he provided a counterexample to show that the pointwise limit of measurable function may not be measurable if the range is not metrizable.

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]))$ and let $Y$ be $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ with the product topology. For each $n$ let $f_n: X\to Y$ be the function that takes $x$ to the element of $Y$ (i.e., to the function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$) given by $t\mapsto \max (0,1-n|t-x|)$.

If I'm not going wrong, $f_n$ converges to $t\mapsto \mathbb{1}_{x=t}(x)$. However, this limit function seems measurable, which is not a counterexample. where do I go wrong?

Comment: No, $(f_n)_n$ converges to the function $f\colon x\in[0,1]\mapsto (t\in[0,1]\to\mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}(t))$.

Comment: @ClementC.: How is that any different?

Comment: @copper.hat I read the OP as $f_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} (t\mapsto \mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}(t))$, instead of $f_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} (x\mapsto (t\mapsto \mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}(t)))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B$ be any non-Borel set in $[0,1]$. Consider $\{\phi \in [0,1]^{[0,1]}:\phi (t)>1/2$ for some $t \in B\}$. This set is an open set in $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$. The inverse image of this set  under  $f$ is precisely $B$, Hence $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: +1: Nice counterexample.