# Is the limit of a sequence of a random variable in the tail algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a sequence of i.i.d random variables $X_n$, is the event $\{\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n \  exists\}$ in the tail algebra?

Intuitively, this should be true because the limit only depends on the tail. However, how do one prove this formally? I rewrite the event into the form $\cup_{c \in \mathbb R}\{\lim_n{X_n} = c\}$,and it seems not hard to prove that $\{\lim_{n}X_n = c\}$ is in the tail event, but it is an uncountable union.

update: I should probably reformulate the event using the Cauchy Criterion so that it is no longer an uncountable union of things. But I am not sure whether that works or not.

Comment: Yes, using cauchy criterion is a good idea.

Comment: Is that the only possible way? Intuitively speaking, this statement should be true for random variables between arbitrary measure spaces equipped with topology. But Cauchy criterion only works if your target space is Banach. @saz

Comment: I'm not aware of other proofs. It is not at all trivial that  $\{\lim_n X_n \, \, \text{exists}\}$ is actually an event (that is, an element of the underlying $\sigma$-algebra). A side remark: In "fancy" spaces it may happen that the pointwise limit $\lim_n X_n$ is not measurable even if it exists, see e.g. this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2736279/36150).